# Get Ajax response to table's td input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve Ajax response to `<td>` row input but it's not working as expected, it's binding to input but when trying to add another product to row it's replacing previous one.

Example 1:

[image]

In above example as you can see first I have added "Camera" to the row and then trying to add another product i.e "Mobile" but it's replacing first one.

Then I have tried another approach but it's not retrieving data in input field.

Example 2:

[image]

In above example it's successfully adding data to the next row but it's not editable.

HTML:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" id="mytable">
        <div class="row">
           <div>
            <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control"> //To search product by id
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add Row</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name=" addmore[0][name]" id="pname" class="form-control"/></td> //This part commented in Example 2
        <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][qty]" id="qty" class="form-control"/></td> //This part commented in Example 2
        <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][price]" id="price" class="form-control"/></td> //This part commented in Example 2
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Script to retrieve data (Example 1):

```
<script>
$('#search').on('keydown', function(e) {
if(e.which == 13){
var proid = $("#search").val();
//alert(proid);
$.ajax({
        url: '{{ URL::to('search-product/')}}'+"/"+ proid,
        type: "Get",    
        dataType:"json",   
        success: function (response) 
       {
            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
            $('#pname').val(item.product_name);
            $('#qty').val(1);
            $('#price').val(item.product_price);
            });
        }
    });
}
});
</script>
```

Script to retrieve data (Example 2):

```
<script>
$('#search').on('keydown', function(e) {
if(e.which == 13){
var proid = $("#search").val();
//alert(proid);
$.ajax({
        url: '{{ URL::to('search-product/')}}'+"/"+ proid,
        type: "Get",    
        dataType:"json",   
        success: function (response) 
       {
            var trHTML = '';
            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.product_name +
                    '</td><td>' + '1' +
                    '</td><td>' + item.product_price +
                    '</td></tr>';
            });
            $('#mytable').append(trHTML);
        }
    });
}
});
</script>
```

Script to add and remove rows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 0;
    $("#add").click(function(){
        ++i;
        $("#mytable").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][name]" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][qty]" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][price]" class="form-control" /></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr">Remove</button></td></tr>');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){  
         $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: In the second approach you are creating a table and setting the contents of the table (that's why it's not editable). To make it editable you have to create new inputs of type text within the table and then set the values of the inputs, not the contents of the table.

Comment: I have created text inputs within table but in Ajax success function how to retrieve them? one example please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to my comment, replace in the 2nd example:

```
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
   trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.product_name +
       '</td><td>' + '1' +
       '</td><td>' + item.product_price +
       '</td></tr>';
});
$('#mytable').append(trHTML);
```

with:

```
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
    trHTML += '<tr>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name=" addmore[0][name]" id="pname' + item.product_name  + '" class="form-control" value="' + item.product_name + '"/></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name=" addmore[0][qty]" id="qty'   + item.product_name  + '" class="form-control" value="1"/></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name=" addmore[0][price]" id="price' + item.product_name  + '" class="form-control" value="' + item.product_price + '"/></td>' +
              '</tr>';
});
$('#mytable').append(trHTML);
```

Comment: Since you are adding multiple items in the table I have edited the answer where I concatenate the ```id``` with the product name since ```id```'s of elements have to be unique. Let me know if it works. If it does and you are satisfied, mark the question as completed.

Comment: Perfect as expected :)

Comment: May I know where it's useful to concatenate id with product name?

Comment: @glitchy If you look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id you can see that the ```id``` attribute has to be unique. Since you are adding multiple products the input elements all have to have unique ```id```'s. By concatenating it with the product name you are therefore giving it a unique id.

Comment: need your little help... how can I access it's value `name='name'` `name='qty'` `name='price'` to save my form? using `<form method="POST">`

Comment: @glitchy give your form an id. Something like ```<form method="POST" id="productForm">```. Then you select the form like so: ```var form = $("#productForm")[0];```. Then you create a new form object like so: ```var formData = new FormData(form);```. This object then contains all the data of your form.

Comment: Means I have to use Ajax method to save my form?

Comment: To see the contents of the form you can do:

```for(var i of formData.entries()){console.log(i); //Do whatever with i}```

Comment: @glitchy AJAX is nice if you want to save it to the database, yes. Otherwise you can just ```POST``` it to the PHP file you are using to save the data. Then you need to do so: ```<form method="POST" id="productForm" action="thePHPfile.php">```